# Failing requests.post when using json.dumps

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Using Python 3.5 and requests 2.18.4 I need to send data to another service, and it is currently failing for some reason.
Sending is made after I receive and clean data from another service, and eventually get the data verified and set as a native python dict.
This works when the data is hardcoded and I am not using the incoming data (hardcoded json string):

```
def my_post_method(self, url, data):
    # import requests (above)
    return requests.post(
        url,
        data='{"keyA":"valA", "keyB":"valB" ... }',
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    ) # status 200
```

But I cannot send it with the original data for some reason.

```
def my_post_method(self, url, data):
    # import requests, json (above)
    d = json.dumps(data)
    return requests.post(
        url,
        data=d,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    ) # status 400
```

d from above: `{"keyA":"valA", "keyB":"valB" ... }`

I tried to use the requests json parameter instead of data, but the other service is apparently expecting data parameter on the other end.
Does it mean that the service I am posting to is waiting on a json-formatted string?

Comment: Can we know the other service? Is it something public that we can try?

Comment: Have you tried making the POST with the hard-coded string again? Is it possible that the service is returning 400s because it doesn't want you to make the same request twice?

Comment: Thank @Rob Watts, but I answered below- for some odd reason, ordering of keys-values was taken into consideration when the receiving end was verifying the incoming data. I really don't know why...

Comment: @camelBack I had a similar problem and discovered running dumps twice on the payload worked. The second dumps escapes all of the double quotes in the json string from the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the argument `json` in `requests.post` that accepts Python dictionaries, if you are using at least version 2.4.2 of requests, avoiding `json.dumps` completely.

[More complicated requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

EDIT:
I can't reproduce the problem in any way, `json` should work, it's the only correct way to send a json with a post in modern `requests`.

Comment: I cannot- it fails when I do (I wrote above)
Should I downgrade my requests? (2.18.4->2.4.2)

Comment: Did you try with `json` without specifying a content type?

Comment: Yes, still failing

Comment: Are you getting the code using `status_code` from the `Response` object that you `return`?
Did you wrote the other service?

Comment: response = my_post_method(url, data) -->  THEN -->
status = response.status_code

Comment: I will try a few more options- I also need to contact the responsible personal at the other service. brb

Comment: Apparently the other service were using ordering for their verification... :(
I don't know why they were, but I asked them to not verify by order of keys.
Thank you @GendoIkari :)

Comment: @camelBack the order of the keys definitely shouldn't matter - http://json.org/ specification is "an *unordered* set of name/value pairs".

Comment: Exactly- I was extremely surprised they chose to do that on the other end